# Executing extremely slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql, select, join

this query has multiple `JOIN` including **aggregate** functions

executing this query for approximately 6000 users took 20 seconds.

is there any other method to run this query faster?

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(orders.totalCost) AS bought, COUNT(comment.id) AS commentsCount, COUNT(topics.id) AS topicsCount, COUNT(users_login.id) AS loginCount, COUNT(users_download.id) AS downloadsCount 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN orders ON users.id=orders.userID AND orders.status=1 
LEFT JOIN comment ON users.id=comment.userID 
LEFT JOIN topics ON users.id=topics.userID 
LEFT JOIN users_login ON users.id=users_login.userID 
LEFT JOIN users_download ON users.id=users_download.userID 
WHERE users.id='$userID'
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY `bought` DESC
```

The result of running explain
[image]

Comment: Make sure you have your table columns properly indexed.

Comment: @PHPglue can you explain more? or give me an example? i know about Primary Key & Unique index but i don't have enough information for index key

Comment: WHat is the result of running EXPLAIN?

Comment: @JimGarrison see my updates. i dont have enough information for EXPLAIN result, if the result have problem please help me to solve it :)

Comment: 'Impossible WHERE noticed ..... '! Also I see only one row in the explain result but you have 6 tables?

Comment: @Gervs excuse me i had a problem in the explain query, see updates

Comment: When you say "run for 2000 users" - how did you do it? Did you loop the query? It looks like you have 6000 users in the DB

Comment: Yes, remove the WHERE clause. Just run the query once - FOR ALL USERS !

Comment: Additionally it seems that not one single join can use an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXPLAIN output shows you are doing full-table scans on everything except `users`.  You need to create secondary (non-unique) indexes on `userID` on all the other tables in the join.  That will speed up queries on individual users.

However, if you're going to process all users in one pass then do a single select without a `WHERE users.id=` clause. Your aggregation returns only one row per user and you should create a single resultset containing all the rows and iterate over that, instead of reissuing the query once per user.  In this case the secondary indexes may still help as counts can be determined from the index alone without looking at the tables themselves.